# Creating struct compatible to matlab in scipy

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

How could we create a struct compatible to matlab in scipy?

For example I have and hiearchical structure as:

```
             1 :x1
       task    :y1
             2 :x2
               :y2
```

We could see it as inverted tree. In the tree, there are two independent brances and each branch has features and labels. I tried to use  `scipy.io.savemat`  but it seems, there is not possiblity to create such structure. Could someone suggest me how could we do it?